# Tests for JUnit. How?

Tags: junit, testing

How is the JUnit Framework tested ?

How are the tests for their framework code created, considering that JUnit as a testing framework itself.

What technology are they using ? Their own testing framework ? A smaller more basic version of it ? Another framework ?

Can any knower please provide some details ?

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that they test using their own framework - why wouldn't they?

Looking at the [source](http://junit.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/junit/junit-ant-tests/src/test/net/saff/ant/FileMatchersTest.java?revision=1.1&view=markup), they do.

Comment: I assume the question is being asked as it's a bit chicken and egg, ie how do you start writing the tests if the framework doesn't exist yet.

Comment: You write enough of the framework to make a simple test, then expand from there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the framework is tested with itself.  I'm sure I remember reading it in [Kent Becks TDD book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Test-Driven-Development-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321146530).  Might be mistaken though.

Answer (score 1):

Who watches the watchmen?

I've read the authors of JUnit are test driven developers so in theory they would have written the unit tests before the wrote the JUnit classes themselves. I also remember that they wrote the first version for Smalltalk and JUnit was a port/upgrade of the Smalltalk suite.